# RTL1892CU WIFI USB Stick not working stable?

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, yocto

I have a RTL1892CU wifi usb stick which i am trying to run stable on yocto linux.
It is running fine but when i unplug the usb and then plug it again it stops working. It desnt say anything about the error but it doesnot get an IP from the AP.
In order to make it work either i have to restart the system or type command:

```
dmesg -C
```

Logs after plugging the usb for the first time are

```
[   33.129763] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number                               2 using ehci-platform
[   33.351676] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=7392, idProduct=7811, bcd                              Device= 2.00
[   33.358455] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   33.379746] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[   33.383107] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[   33.387191] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[   33.593936] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory d                              atabase
[   33.682840] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   33.905544] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[   34.018440] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   34.020782] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   34.026348] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   34.050846] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   34.069671] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   34.228300] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   34.268704] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   38.552443] wlan0: authenticate with 92:9d:68:94:d8:6f
[   38.586600] wlan0: send auth to 92:9d:68:94:d8:6f (try 1/3)
[   38.599408] wlan0: authenticated
[   38.609928] wlan0: associate with 92:9d:68:94:d8:6f (try 1/3)
[   38.629800] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 92:9d:68:94:d8:6f (capab=0x431 status=0                               aid=1)
[   38.658315] wlan0: associated
[   38.663567] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 0 (-128 - 0) dBm as advertised by 92:                              9d:68:94:d8:6f
[   39.089956] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[   39.308201] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

When i unplug the usb it shows

```
root@user:~# [  142.320842] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  142.361473] wlan0: deauthenticating from 92:9d:68:94:d8:6f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  142.370593] rtl_usb: reg 0x102, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0xd30000
[  142.378271] rtl_usb: reg 0x422, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0xf00069ce
[  142.386621] rtl_usb: reg 0x542, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x69543421
[  142.395084] rtl_usb: reg 0x1cc, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x69543421
```

after plugging it again it shows..

```
root@user:~# [  184.211693] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-platform
[  184.413615] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=7392, idProduct=7811, bcdDevice= 2.00
[  184.420515] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  184.429866] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[  184.434632] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  184.437317] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[  184.445634] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[  184.559752] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[  184.562338] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[  184.567784] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[  184.576555] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
```

How can i solve this problem? Thank you!

**Update:**
On unplugging the device manually it shows..

```
root@user# [  293.874491] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  293.913290] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:4e:35:99:ce:a0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

and then on replugging it the logs are..

```
root@user# [  392.603244] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-platform
[  392.805378] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=7392, idProduct=7811, bcdDevice= 2.00
[  392.812316] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  392.821606] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[  392.826236] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  392.829057] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[  392.841273] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[  392.954756] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[  392.957229] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[  392.962859] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[  392.969672] ieee80211 phy5: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
```

Phy keeps on increasing everytime

Comment: I am using yocto linux. It doesnt says anything about card not working but the problem is that it doesnt take the IP from the AP on reconnecting it, so i assume there is some problem with the device drivers. Which actual messages should i post? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I have added that in the question.